# Appending and Sorting div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let me show us my scenario and my problem.

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/WEtML/1/) is a list of div that are ordered by the content of `categories1` alphabetically by jQuery when the page is loaded :

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="categories">
        <div class="categories1">
            Ernest
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="categories">
        <div class="categories1">
            Andy
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="categories">
        <div class="categories1">
            Mark
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

// result
Andy
Ernest
Mark
```

[Now](http://jsfiddle.net/WEtML/2/), when I try to append an element and then ordering the elements, there is a trouble : in fact the last element inserted is not ordered, but it's just appended at the end of the list :

```
<div class="categories">
    <div class="categories1">
        Buddy
    </div>
</div>

// result
Andy
Ernest
Mark
Buddy
```

This is the sorting function :

```
$(function() {
    var items = $('.categories1').get();

    items.sort(function(x,y) {
      return $(x).text() > $(y).text();
    });

    $('#container').empty();

    $(items).each(function() {
        $('#container').append($(this).parent());
    });
});
```

Why this behaviour? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Just re-sort the items each time you append.

Comment: Is what I do, but it doesnt works : check the Fiddles examples

Comment: Please show your sort-call. Is it possible that this is a timing problem? Sort before insert maybe?

Comment: Added the sort-function. You can show the whole code from the Fiddle links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best fix, but you could [`$.trim`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) the text: http://jsfiddle.net/WEtML/4/

```
items.sort(function(x,y) {
    return $.trim($(x).text()) > $.trim($(y).text());
});
```

Comment: Exactly what I was about to say, as marsbear said below, you have a whitespace problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have a whitespace problem. Inspect your markup after inserting. The first items start with a space and Buddy does not.

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="categories">
    <div class="categories1"> Andy </div>
  </div>
  <div class="categories">
    <div class="categories1"> Ernest </div>
  </div>
  <div class="categories">
    <div class="categories1"> Mark </div>
  </div>
  <div class="categories">
    <div class="categories1">Buddy</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @markzzz Can you please update your second example with the whitespace fix?

Comment: Yes, this rocks. But it doesnt resolve my "real problem", because the string that I append is from a JSON object, and it's the same as the elements...

Comment: thirtydot posted the fix. Just use trim to remove trailing whitespace on sorting (or even befor when you insert) and it should work.